# How to split a column of data into two columns based on other matching column criteria in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, database, transpose

I have a database list of products and their components but often have multiple sizes. I'm looking for a formula based method to split a separate size of the same items into a second column for user-friendly viewing. I've tried pivot tables which I couldn't get to work, and I really would prefer not to do this manually (we have thousands of entries).

The first table is the original source I have, and the second is the table I would like it to become.

[image: example]

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Why does it become `B-2 Size`? I would've expected `A-2 Size`. You need to better explain your before/after, especially since this is an example of 6 records and your real table has thousands.

Comment: Oh the headers are just vanity, they don't have to be renamed; sorry if it was confusing. But yes, technically they would be the same as A-2 size.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use a PivotTable.

[image: img1]

Field settings:

[image: img2]

Long answer: What you're looking for (exactly) cannot be achieved via a PivotTable, but you could achieve it through formulas (probably) or VBA (definitely). However, you'll need to demonstrate an attempt on your part before we can help you with that, or at least provide a clear, concise before & after. As your current example stands, there's no way we can predict what that would look like on a large scale.

Comment: Okay, I thought it could be a simple formula that I wasn't familiar with. I've tried with Pivot Tables already and could not get the ideal clean setup, because some items actually have more than 2 sizes. A formulaic lookup or match would probably be ideal. I'll poke around some more myself.

Comment: @user2337231 The formula would have to be an array formula, which can be a pain if you're not familiar with them and are taxing to the worksheet. VBA would be the cleanest solution, IMO.